# Relative asymptotic behavior of these functions

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have 3 functions: `f(n)=2`<sup>`n`</sup>, `g(n)=n!` and `h(n)=n`<sup>*log*`(n)`</sup> (*log*`(n)` is base 2).

Comparing `f(n)` and `g(n)`: The factorial function, `g(n)` can be approximated as `O(n`<sup>`n`</sup>`)` (poor upper bound). Considering this, Is `g(n)=Ω(f(n))` ?

How would I compare `g(n)` and `h(n)`, and `f(n)` and `h(n)`?

Comment: This sure seems like homework.

Comment: Almost a homework. I have tagged it so, as well.

Comment: The answer to your first question is "no." The reverse is true. `f(n)` grows slower than `g(n)`. Try using the definition to prove stuff.

Comment: Yes. f(n)=Ω(g(n). I made a mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Shallow answers for homework)

Use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for factorial function to study it's asymptotic.

For second question, If you have difficulties studying functions as they're given, try to study logarithms of them.  Then infer the relationship between given functions based on the results you've obtained for logarithms (these results won't be equivalent!)